# How to get read the iCloud/iTunes synced photos

Tags: ios, iphone, alassetlibrary

I am developing an application, in that my job is to access the photos from the photo library using `AssetsLibrary`. But I'm facing following problems:

1. When I try to access the burst photos
2. Try to access the synced photos from iTunes/iCloud.

So please help me how to access the burst photos and synced photos using `AssetsLibrary`.

Answer (score 0):

This method is for `Photos` framework.

If you already got the `PHAsset`, you can access the asset's data by following:

```
// For image
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [PHImageRequestOptions new];
options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
options.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionCurrent;
options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;

//If comes from iCloud, the progressHandler will be called. 
options.progressHandler = ^(double progress, NSError *__nullable error, BOOL *stop, NSDictionary *__nullable info) {
    NSLog(@"percent:%f, info:%@", progress, info);
    // Handle progress
};

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:options resultHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable imageData, NSString * _Nullable dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
    if (imageData) {
        // Handle data
    }
}];


// For video
PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [PHVideoRequestOptions new];
options.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionCurrent;
options.deliveryMode = PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
options.progressHandler = ^(double progress, NSError * _Nullable error, BOOL * _Nonnull stop, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
    NSLog(@"percent:%f, info:%@", progress, info);
    // Handle progress
};

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset * _Nullable asset, AVAudioMix * _Nullable audioMix, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
    AVURLAsset *avurlasset = (AVURLAsset*)asset;
    // Handle data
}];
```

Get assets:

```
PHFetchResult *userLibrary = [PHAssetCollection
                              fetchAssetCollectionsWithType:PHAssetCollectionTypeSmartAlbum
                              subtype:PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumUserLibrary
                              options:nil];

[userLibrary enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    PHAssetCollection *assetCollection = (PHAssetCollection *)obj;
    PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [self getFetchResultInAssetCollection:assetCollection];
    [fetchResult enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        PHAsset *asset = (PHAsset *)obj;
        // Handle asset
    }];
}];
```

-getFetchResultInAssetCollection:

```
-(PHFetchResult *)getFetchResultInAssetCollection:(PHAssetCollection *)assetCollection {
    PHFetchOptions *options = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
    // video and image
    options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType = %d || mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaTypeImage, PHAssetMediaTypeVideo];
    // Sort by creationDate
    options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];

    PHFetchResult *fetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:assetCollection options:options];

    return fetchResult;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tom,but I want to do this one using AssetLibrary not photo framework

Comment: @venkat OK, https://github.com/donobono/DoImagePickerController may be helpful to you.

Comment: @venkat This repository use `AssetLibrary` in `AssetHelper` to handle photos.

Comment: ,in that they didn't mention any information about the burst and synced photos